# Add events into fullcalendar using JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, fullcalendar

i have a JSON string here:

```
[{"title":"Event","start":"2017-04-23T18:00:00","end":"2017-04-23T18:00:00"},{"title":"Event 2","start":"2017-04-23T11:15:00","end":"2017-04-23T11:15:00"},{"title":"Event 3","start":"2017-04-26T08:32:00","end":"2017-04-26T08:32:00"}]
```

how can I add those events in my calendar? (maybe using a loop?)

Comment: Just do this. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_array/

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: [
        {
            title  : 'event1',
            start  : '2010-01-01'
        },
        {
            title  : 'event2',
            start  : '2010-01-05',
            end    : '2010-01-07'
        },
        {
            title  : 'event3',
            start  : '2010-01-09T12:30:00',
            allDay : false // will make the time show
        }
    ]
});
```